# Two external displays from one laptop with VGA and HDMI?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have Sony VGN-FW560F with ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4650. I would like to hook up two external monitors to a laptop's Hdmi and Vga. The laptop graphic card normally only support 2 displays and I want those two displays on the external ones. I don't want to use USB to VGA adapter. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost possible... I have hacked(literally) the VGA head which is very close to HDMI  port for both VGA and HDMI to plug at the same time. I disable the laptop monitor and close the lid and try to enable the both external monitors. Alas, my graphic card model is one series below to achieve that since someone with ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470 is able to do that following the same route. http://forums.overclockers.co.uk/showthread.php?t=18404870